# silverlight read email

Tags: silverlight, email

I'm using VS2010, C#, silverlight 4, I'm going to read gmail, yahoo and outlook accounts and display their inboxes, (gmail & yehoo have more importance), how can I do that? it is almost straightforward in ASP.NET using SMTP, but how is it done using silverlight?
I've seen a very similar question, but I'm searching for some practical code if possible

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a WCF service that will be facade to real SMTP server calls which will be done on server, and use some WCF api to manipulate those email accounts from silverlight->WCF->Server SMTP calls.